# pass variable value to template after receiving a POST request every 5 sec

Tags: python, ajax, flask

The problem is after I get a request and I assign value to variable `msg` my template `login.html` is still empty and I want to see message = 'got it'.

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/req', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def req():
    msg = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.values.get('name', None) == 'asdf':
            msg = 'got it'
    #print msg - variable msg = 'got it'
    return render_template('login.html', msg=msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

login.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="static/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var test = function() {
        $(function() {
             $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/req",
                data: {'name': 'asdf'},
            });    
        });
    }
    window.setInterval(function() {
      test()
    }, 5000);
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
  {% if msg %}
    {{ msg }} #empty page
  {% endif %}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're mixing up template rendering and Ajax.

Your JavaScript `test` function *does* call your `req` view method in the back-end, which *does* render a template, but you're not doing anything with that template.

Your `msg` variable that you're attempting to print in the template where you have your `# empty page` note will never be rendered, as there's no `msg` variable that isn't `None` at the time the base template is rendered. `msg` is set by the POSTing via Ajax, but that rendered template is never displayed.

If your goal is to just see the `msg` output on the page, have your `req` method just return that on a `POST`:

```
@app.route('/req', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def req():
    msg = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.values.get('name', None) == 'asdf':
            return 'got it'
    return render_template('login.html', msg=msg)
```

And in your Ajax call,

```
var test = function() {
    $(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/req",
            data: {'name': 'asdf'},
            success: function(data) {
                // do something with your 'got it' string
            }
        });    
    });
}
```

If you really want to return your template as you have it written in the question, you're much better off with a form to submit instead of Ajax so you'll browse to the new page:

```
@app.route('/req', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def req():
    msg = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.values.get('name', None) == 'asdf':
            render_template('login.html', msg=msg)
    return render_template('login.html', msg=None)
```

And the HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="static/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  </head>
  <body>
  <form action="/req" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
  {% if msg %}
    {{ msg }} #empty page
  {% endif %}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thx for your answer. do you know the proper way of doing this ?

Comment: Added more to answer; see if that helps.